# Web Part Error

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

One of the SharePoint out-of-the box (created with SharePoint tools and no custom code) web parts has suddenly stopped working, offering only this information to debug:

```
Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or   imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.
```

I am lost at to why all the other parts (Custom code and just content) seem to load, but just this one is looking for type/dll throwing the exception.

Where to start debugging and what pieces of SharePoint I have to learn now?

I checked the log on where the app is hosted and found no issues directly pointing to the issue.

Not many issues at all except: Fialed to compile audiences.
Can this be an issue for a text.

Comment: Did you check the logs? Sp2007 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\LOGS", Sp2010 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\LOGS"

Comment: Was it created with SharePoint Designer? More information about the web part would probably be helpful.

Comment: @dexter: Why is the question tagged with C#? Is it a data view web part? Data form web part? What is the web part's data source? Any other info you can include will help. Also, have you tried recreating the web part?

Answer (score 1):

While adding custom web part to a sharepoint site
In the `Web.config` file, add the following element under the `SafeControls` element:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Namespace="NamespaceName" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

For more refer this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939306

Comment: This is not best practice to make changes in web.config by hands. If you work with Sharepoint 2007 you should do it programmaticaly. If you work with SharePoint 2010, you can set safe controls withing package configuration -> Advances, look at Visual Studio project and make changes. If you'll make changes by hands, there is some risk, that after redeploying this or other solution to the farm your changes will disappear.